# ID for cell in 1x1 html table?

Tags: html, html-table, background-image, cell

Can I find or give a 1x1 html table cell an ID?

I would like to use `document.getElementById.style.background` to dynamically change the background image of a cell.

Comment: You can give an ID to any DOM element, cell is not different

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you have a table of 1x1 cells is it possibly you are trying to use that to display something that might be better displayed with a `<canvas>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I was using a table cell to keep things correctly positioned.  I got the following code working:

document.getElementById("frameCell").style.backgroundImage="url('myBackgroundImage.jpg')";

for use by:

:)